# Android: ScrollView does not re-size when adding child views

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a ScrollView that I am trying to populate dynamically. Here is the XML that contains the ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f6f5f5" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#40ff0000"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_list_container"
        android:background="#40ffff00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#292929"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Stap 3/5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is the XML for the element I'm inserting in the ScrollvVew:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<np.custom.FontIcon
    android:id="@+id/option_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_circleround"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/planit_selection_empty_circle"
    android:textColor="#292929" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code I use to populate the scrollview:

```
    ArrayList<String> g = new ArrayList<String>();
    g.add("Fix a Bug");
    g.add("Buy a new PC");
    g.add("Make Coffee");
    g.add("Take a Break");
    g.add("Don't do that");
    g.add("Throw your hands in the air like you just don't care!");
    LinearLayout optionListLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.option_list_container);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    for(String p:g){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planit_option_item, null);
        TextView optText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
        optText.setText(p);
        optionListLayout.addView(v);
    }
```

This all works almost fine, except that the sizes of the ScrollView and the LinearLayout it contains do not come out as I expected. This a screenshot of that it looks like on a device, which shows text being cut out when it goes to a second line:

[image]

So how can I make sure the linear layout re-sizes to accommodate children views of different heights?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't the `ScrollView` not accommodating new children. The problem is that the text, when it spans more than one line, is being clipped due to layout parameters in `R.layout.planit_option_item`. Try changing the `TextView` of ID `@+id/option_text` so that its height is `wrap_content`.

Comment: When I do that it hides even more of the text.

Comment: When you do this with multiple elements that are added programmatically, wrap_content sets height of all the elements based on the height needed to wrap the content of the first element. So this solution could work as long as your first element is always your biggest.

Comment: Wait what? So there's no way to re-size the elements dynamically?

Comment: I'm a little confused about this, because in my own application right now I am adding elements very similar to yours programmatically to a container. Those elements are ones with `TextView`s that are a mixture of one and two lines. The elements' heights are `wrap_content` in my situation, hence my original suggestion. The result I have is that the child elements' heights wrap and vary correctly. I've honestly never come across the feature Cumulo Nimbus mentions and I'd be interested to see documentation to support that. I'll have to think a bit more about why it is not working in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextView for the ScrollView element to accommodate two lines:

```
...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:maxLines="2"         
    android:singleLine="false"  
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
...
```

This is not an issue with ScrollView, it's an issue with the specifications of the element you are inserting into the ScrollView. If you expect there may be more than 2 lines of text in some cases set maxLines = X where X is the maximum number of lines you expect.

Please let me know if this does not work and I would be happy to help further.